# What constraints to set to have an ImageView automatically resize image to a fixed width but dynamic height?

Tags: ios, constraints

I am attempting to have an `UIImageView` autoresize itself to a variable height. The `UIImage` I am using can come in various different dimensions from the network, which is why this is important.

[image]

Imagine the above `UIImageView` is pinned to the top, left, and right. I want the `UIImageView` to resize only it's height based on whatever `UIImage` is downloaded.

Comment: Ever solve this without simply scaling using contentMode or clipping?

Comment: @ÞorvaldurRúnarsson Yep, using the aspect ratio of the photo, I would calculate the height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the ImageView's `Mode` to `Aspect fit`

[image: Screenshot - XCode's Attributes Inspector panel]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12576022)

Comment: Oh, it's a link to an image. SO did not let me put an image here. I'll make it clearer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can have height constraint IBOutlet , When you download image

`UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:dataObj]`

you can have `img.size`

which returns size of image

so just set

`self.heightCons.constant = img.size.height`

and Must `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want that image fit to imageview exactly then you can try `contentMode` property of `imageView`.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

//or

imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

//and

imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

If you hardly want to resize imageView with image's size then you should take outlets of your constraints and play with it's constant.